# How do I remove a member from a Trello board?

Tags: delete, trello-boards

I'm not finding how to remove team members from my Trello board?

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you want to remove Rich from the "Development Board"

1. Open the Development Board
2. Click on Rich's avatar in the Members section
3. Click "Remove from Board"

[image: Remove from Board]

Comment: Note: This is only possible if you're an admin on the board.

Comment: Works also for leaving a board