# If a user is removed from a Trello organization, but didn't get removed from all boards, how do you delete them completely later?

Tags: trello-organization, trello-boards

We had a user that left the organization; in deleting the user from the organization, they didn't get removed from all boards (the wrong option was selected when deleting them at the time). Now that user is still lingering in the system on some cards and I didn't see an obvious way to remove them other than manually removing each instance of the user. Is there an easier way to mass-remove the user when their profile no longer shows up under the organization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [remove the user from each board](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30309/how-do-i-remove-a-member-from-a-trello-board%29) that they are on; that will remove them from all cards on the board.  There is not (currently) an easier way to do this.

Comment: The OP was asking for a bulk capability.

Comment: @Dez Fair enough; I wasn't sure if he was implying that he had to manually remove the user from each card that he was assigned to.  I've updated the answer to indicate that there isn't a mass-remove ability.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've changed my vote as well. :-)

Comment: No mass delete across boards? Then it sounds like you only get one shot to do it and if it's not selected, it's manual time...aw, that's sad. :-/

Answer (score -2):

When remove the user from board member, it stated that the user will still receive notification although now is non member. The problem is I can't find any option to remove Non-Member.